# How to grant Linux read permission for a user to a particular file owned by root?

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

I'm using Amazon Linux (I believe it's based on CentOS) and I'd like to grant read permission to a particular user for a particular file that's owned by root. Is it possible to do while keeping the root ownership of the file but without adding the user to the root group?

Comment: "Keeping the root ownership of the file" – you mean `root:root`? Or may it be `root:foo`?

Comment: OK, so do I keep the file owner as root, but change the group to `foo`, and then add my user to group `foo`?

Comment: You may have to create this group first. Also set the file permissions to make it group-readable. (I allow somebody else to compose good answer with actual commands and take credit, as I'm in a hurry at the moment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the filesystem supports POSIX ACLs, use `setfacl`:

```
setfacl -m user:RTF:r myfile.txt

setfacl -m u:RTF:r myfile.txt
```